# TYPESCRIPT - How to allow for more types in every property of a TypeScript object?

Tags: typescript, object, interface

I have an object in my project. Here is the schema:

```
IObject : {
  prop1: number;
  prop2: number;
}
```

This is the typing I want for 90% of the usages. But a few instances require me to also return a string for every property. So, for a few instances I want an interface that returns:

```
object: IObjectWithStrings // Here I want to add string to each property as acceptable type.

// Something like
object: IObjects extends string
```

How do I do that?? I can create a new inteface just for that, but I would rather have the original interrface and extend it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create another type from the one you have:

```
type IObject = {
    prop1: number;
    prop2: number;
}

type IObjectString = {
    [K in keyof IObject]: string 
}

type IObjectStringOrOriginal = {
    [K in keyof IObject]: string | IObject[K]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using *generics*. In this example, you can define a base type `IObject<T>`, where T represents the dynamic type, like this:

```
type IObject<T> = {
  prop1: T;
  prop2: T;
}
```

Than you can use directly `IObject<number>` or `IObject<number | string>`, where `number | string` means "prop1 is allowed to be one of both" (Union type), or you can just define additional types using the base type `IObject<T>`:

```
type IObjectNumber = IObject<number>;
type IObjectWithString = IObject<number | string>;

const objNum: IObjectNumber = { prop1: 10, prop2: 'abc' } // this will throw error
const objNumStr: IObjectWithString = { prop1: 10, prop2: 'abc' } // this will not throw error
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that. The thing is, that the `object` comes from the DTOs, which should not be change to accept different values, just cause the FE, needs to accept default values with are strings. Nor it should be a generic. Thanks though.. I will upvote, but I cannot accept as correct.